# Cannot call method remove of null

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I do not understand why this is evaluating to be null. Here is the offending code:

Javascript (jQuery) call:

```
<a href="javascript:;" onmousedown="pheonixTag();">,  
  <%= disp %> 
</a>
```

Javascript function:

```
function pheonixTag() {  

  $("#outer_block").remove();

}
```

Relevant bit of HTML:

```
<div id="outer_block"> stuff
  <div id="inner_block"></div>
</div>
```

When i make this call i get the error: Cannot call method remove of null. what gives?

Comment: What version of Rails? Is your layout loading both Prototype and jQuery? They will fight over `$` if you don't use just one or use jQuery's no conflict mode.

Comment: I'm using Rails 3.0.4, I am only loading jquery.

Comment: Ahh, never mind, I just checked and rails loads prototype as part of its 'javascript_include_tag :defaults'! I didn't realise. Thanks so much for the tip. That comment = the answer. If you make it official, I'll accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that $("#outer_block") returns a null reference instead of the real object. I believe you should use $("outer_block")

Answer (score 0):

I suggest dropping down to a dev console or Firebug in Firefox.

From there I would check for returned js errors and type in my selector query on the console to test it's returning an object.

Where is your function phoenixTag?

Comment: thanks for the answer, the issue was that prototype and jQuery were fighting for '$'. Thanks to @Steve for pointing that out.